# Downloading XML Reponse from external URL

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is basic, I am a C++ developer and was tasked to create a webpage...

We work with cameras and I try to download a response from the camera to know what capabilities it has. Then I try to extract those capabilities, and set my div elements to visible or unvisible.

```
    function readAlarmReactions() 
    {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          if (parseXML(xhttp.responseXML, 'Beep') == 'false')
          {
            document.getElementById("Beep").style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "http://172.19.50.231/ISAPI/Event/triggersCap", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

    function parseXML(xml, request) {
      var path = "/EventTriggersCap/isSupport" + request;
      if (xml.evaluate) {
        var nodes= xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var result = nodes.iterateNext();
        if (result) {
          return result.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
        return 'false';
      }
      return 'false';
    }
```

When I run this code, I get to the `xhttp.open()`, but I never reach the `if (parseXML())` inside the readyState. How can I debug what's happening here?

The HTML I use to test with is a local file, so it is run from harddrive, if this makes any difference.

Comment: *"The HTML I use to test with is a local file, so it is run from harddrive, if this makes any difference."* - Yeah, don't do that. Run the HTML from a web server on the same domain (!) as the file you want to fetch via `XMLHttpRequest`. Also, the broweser's console (F12) allows you to see what's going on with your XHRs, you should see an error there right now.

Comment: Its not a file I request, its a website generated by their server in XML format. Does this only work from the same domain?

Comment: The HTML file that runs your script must not be a `file://` request, either. I understood your last sentence that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug what is happening here:

1. Open Firefox
2. Click the three vertical dots on the upper right hand corner of the scroll bar.
3. Click 'More Tools' ->  'Developer Tools'
4. Click 'Sources'
5. Put a breakpoint in the JavaScript where you're having your problem.
6. Debug from here.

Also, you might look into JavaScript Promises.  They're ugly, but they're the more robust solution to what you're looking for.  If a file is large enough and you're trying to process it, the instantaneous execution you're trying to get isn't going to happen.  Article on promises here:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises